# Missing Local DTC in MSDTC

Tags: windows-7-x64, msdtc

First i couldn't start MSDTC service.I tried following link and solve that problem. link : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/winserverhyperv/thread/d3de5460-fb42-4af0-ac75-27c22741c7e9 .Now I'm having problem with missing Local DTC in MSDTC.(I checked with component services).I'm using windows 7(64bit).

I tried following steps too.But still no luck.

1)Stop the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service in the Services Control Panel

2)At a command prompt run "msdtc -uninstall" without quotes. This removes the MSDTC service from the Services Control Panel and the associated service hive along with the CIDs and CID.Locals from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSDTC 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CID 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CID.Local
```

3)Skip this step if you want to preserve existing configuration, such as network transactions and other MSDTC security settings. Otherwise manually delete the following registry keys if they exist:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSDTC 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CID 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CID.Local 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC
```

4)At a command prompt run "msdtc -install" without quotes. This reinstalls the MSDTC service and the 4 registry hives above.

5)At a command prompt run “msdtc –resetlog” without quotes

Any tips on how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now Im bored with solving my own issues.I post it in my blog. http://littlerasika.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/problem-with-starting-msdtc-and-missing-local-dtc-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

There is a section under the

```
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> Distributed Transactions -> Local DTC
```

If you go to properties you should be able to check the "**Network DTC Access**" box and fill the DCT Logon.

I had to mess around with it quite a few times (since my permissions were too tight) also I would suggest to restart after the new settings and do not forget to disable the firewall just for the duration of testing to make sure it is not getting blocked there.

There you go :)

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, for Windows Server 2019, this is the right answer.